# iOS 8.1 Settings "Handoff & Suggested Apps" doesn't exist

Tags: ios, iphone, continuity

I am having difficulty getting Handoff and Continuity working correctly. Devices are iPhone 4S (iOS 8.1) and Mac Mini 2013 (Yosemite 10.10 14A389). Here is what I have done/confirmed:

- Both devices are logged into the same iCloud account
- Both devices are connected to the same WiFi Network
- Both devices have bluetooth enabled
- OSX > System Preferences > General > "Allow Handoff" is checked

My problem is that on the iPhone, Settings > General > Handoff & Suggested Apps does not exist as an option in the list.

I have deleted Bluetooth preferences on OS X as suggested on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150883/how-to-make-continuity-and-handoff-working-iphone-5s-ios-8-1macbook-pro-mid/151856#151856) answer.

Anyone know why this option is not presenting itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handoff is not supported on an iPhone 4S as described in this article:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6337

Comment: iPhone 4S does support voice call continuity, but you are correct. [Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6337) is Apple's official list of supported devices and features for Continuity

Comment: iPhone 4S has bluetooth 4.0 and was the first iPhone to have it and that is confirmed by Apple. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Handoff4S** from the BigBoss repository if your device is jailbroken, which will enable Continuity on iPhone 4s and allow the option to be shown in Settings.